# datatable js DOM elements positioning issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables

I have a small formatting issue. It can be because I don't fully understand the   data tables formatting.

HTML code

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
<h1 class="page-header">Test Runs</h1>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="tests">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Link</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>ipsum</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>1,001</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>ipsum</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The outer div is present because i have a side menu bar which is not shown here.

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tests').DataTable( {
    dom:
        "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-3'i><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'p>>"
} );
```

} );

In the above js code, if I don't add "dom" element the filter results and search bar are not in the same row , they are one below the other.
The same applies to information and pagination.

I want the four elements to be in four corners of the screen.
eg:

- length changing input control : top left
- filtering input : top right
- table information summary : bottom left
- pagination control : bottom right.

With the current code (with  the "dom" added) I am able to achieve this but now there is a horizontal scroll which I don't want.

Can someone tell me what mistake I made.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the relevant elements in the bootstrap panel.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"panel panel-default"<"panel-heading"<"row"<"col-md-6"l><"col-md-6 text-right"f>>>t<"panel-footer"<"row"<"col-md-6"i><"col-md-6 text-right"p>>>>'
}); });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a62hqqf9/

You can also look again for the use of DOM elements : [datatable dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

Comment: Fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for horizontal scroll is negative margins of `.row`. You need to remove negative margins with custom class. I have added `.no-gutters` in the snippet example as you are probably using Bootstrap 3. If you are using Bootstrap 4, the class comes with Bootstrap CSS.

Demo: [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/rhythm19/n7mfy1rs/)